# jQuery Datatables show page numbers at top

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatables with pagination numbers at the bottom of the table. However, I would like to move it to the top since when the page numbers are changes, because of the amount of data (also iDisplayLength set as 100), user requires to scroll at the top everytime, which is annoying.

Here is my code:

```
     $(function() 
     {
      oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 100,
        "sDom": '<"top"<"actions">fpi<"clear">><"clear">rt<"bottom">',
    });
});
```

This seems to work, but it removes my 'Show entries' drow-down, where I give an option for someone to select number of entries to show on page and also removes my styles.

Comment: I think you are missing the `l` (of length), try `lfpi`. [DataTables sDom](http://datatables.net/usage/options#sDom).

Comment: Yep, I noticed, it works now, thanks for pointing though, does the actions need to be replaced with css class in order to get back the styles?

Comment: I don't know what were your previous styles. What was your code? I used custom classes, so I don't know which are the default ones. Try to use the default code and explore the generated classes with [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) or something like that, and them apply them.

Comment: figured out this one, thanks azeos for your comments.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by [@azeos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536753/jquery-datatables-show-page-numbers-at-top#comment32522149_21536753), you are missing `l` in [`sDom`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#sDom). Corrected code is shown below:

```
$(function(){
   var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
       "bJQueryUI": true,
       "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
       "iDisplayLength": 100,
       "sDom": '<"top"<"actions">lfpi<"clear">><"clear">rt<"bottom">'
   });
});
```

See [`sDom`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#sDom) (DataTables 1.9) or [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) (DataTables 1.10+) for more information.